# What Spring has to do with static context

Tags: java, spring, static

I removed `static` from DAO methods and sessionFactory. Now IDE makes me switch back to use static DAO methods because it says `Non-static method updatePrice(long) cannot be referenced form a static context`. Neither of classes includes static keyword. What's wrong? How to fix it?

**ServiceActionDAO**

```
@Transactional
public class ServiceActionDAO{
 @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void insert(ServiceActionEntity paramServiceAction){
        Transaction localTransaction = null;
        try{
            Session localSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            localSession.save(paramServiceAction);
            localSession.getTransaction().commit();
ServiceOrderDAO.updatePrice(paramServiceAction.getServiceOrderFk().longValue());// error
        }
        catch (Exception localException){
            if (localTransaction != null) {
                localTransaction.rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

UPDATE

I find a quick way to solve this problem by replacing error line with:

```
new ServiceOrderDAO().updatePrice(paramServiceAction.getServiceOrderFk().longValue());
```

Now it's not a static call.

---

UPDATE 2

I have a lot of DAO classes and a number of controllers. I have to find quick fix with minimum code changes taking into account Spring architecture. I have one DAO calls one or more DAOs to perform some complex queries.

As was denoted before: creating new instance of DAO would lead to unpredictable Spring  session behavior.

It appears that my controllers also have calls for DAO classes.

What is the easiest way (with minimum code changes) to fix this problem?

---

UPDATE 3

Ended up injecting DAO into DAOs and Controllers. It seems like quick fix but from the conceptual point of view I doubt that this is the best solution...

Comment: `updatePrice` is not a `static` method but you're trying to invoke it statically...Please search for the error message.

Comment: Try really hard not to ever use `static` except when declaring constants. In all other cases, avoid it. Your Dao should not be static, and it should not have static methods. It is a spring bean and needs to be instantiated with spring so that the transactional aspect can intercept calls onto its methods -- this cannot happen if it is in any way static.

Comment: And you should get the Dao from spring someway (usually by injecting it into your controllers, or by direct reference to the spring context). If you create a new instance as you have above, your transactions will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

a) inject a reference to your ServiceOrderDAO into the ServiceActionDao, and call the method on the injected DAO instance, or

b) you can introduce a service layer that calls both DAOs in the same transaction, where each DAO is injected into the service.

Either way you have to make both of the DAOs spring-managed beans.

If you have a situation where you're needing to call one DAO from another DAO it seems like introducing a service would be an appropriate solution.

Also the commit and rollback are unnecessary and even counterproductive here. When using Spring you should be able to remove this code without a problem.

Making a new instance of the DAO is not a great solution because it's not a Spring-managed bean. If it has autowired properties then those won't get set. If it's using its own SessionFactory, different from the autowired one, then you will get strange behavior as it will be using a different session than Spring-managed DAOs.

Comment: Can you please give quick exampel code how can I make **b)**? I have ` <context:component-scan base-package="dao" />` so I think all my DAO is spring-managed beans. Right?

Comment: @RCola: you need a Repository annotation on the DAO. for an example you could start with https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/